# UIInterfaceOrientation Xcode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiinterfaceorientation

I would like my app to support PortraitUpSideDown orientation.
I have changed the info.p list to reflect this and tried to implement the change on one view as a test

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    return YES;
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    return YES;

}
```

But the view does not respond.
Do I need to implement this on all views before the app responds?
Is there a Xib setting I need to change?

Comment: This is not an Xcode question. It's a ____ question, where you fill in the blank with the display library you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to support both landscape orientations, try the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Or:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Or somethings that looks like what you were trying to write:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        return YES;
    }
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sch for these solutions the app does not seem to respond it is a Tab Bar app maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: @sch The last code snippet worked with the following solution in the apple discussion forums https://discussions.apple.com/message/8544354#8544354
Thanks for the help!